# How to add encryption to boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig for s3 file upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload a file to s3 using boto3 file_upload method. This is pretty straight forward until server side encryption is needed. In the past I have used put_object to achieve this.

Like so:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=object_name,
                             Body=data,
                             ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms',
                             SSEKMSKeyId='alias/aws/s3')
```

I now want to upload files directly to s3 using the file_upload method. I can't find how to add server side encryption to the file_upload method. The file_upload method can take a [TransferConfig](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig) but I do not see any arguments that set the encryption but I do see them in [S3Transfer](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer).

I am looking for something like this:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
tc = boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig(ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms',
                                      SEKMSKeyId='alias/aws/s3')
s3.upload_file(file_name, 
               bucket, 
               object_name,
               Config=tc)
```

boto3 documentation

- [file_upload](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)
- [TransferConfig](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig)

Comment: If I read this correctly, the 4th parameter to S3.Client.upload_file() seems to be extraArgs. Are you able to supply ExtraArgs={ServerSideEncryption:'aws:kms', SSEKMSKeyId:'alias/aws/s3'}. Note spelling of SSEKMSKeyId (not SEKMSKeyId).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to come up with two solutions with jarmod's help.

**Using boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer**

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3', 'us-west-2')
transfer = boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer(client=client)
transfer.upload_file(file_name,
                     bucket, 
                     key_name,
                     extra_args={'ServerSideEncryption':'aws:kms', 
                                 'SSEKMSKeyId':'alias/aws/s3'}
)
```

**Using s3.meta.client**

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(file_name, 
                           bucket, key_name, 
                           ExtraArgs={'ServerSideEncryption':'aws:kms',
                                      'SSEKMSKeyId':'alias/aws/s3'})
```

Answer (score 0):

you donot pass SSEKMSKeyId in boto3 api if you want to use s3 kms, by default, it uses s3 kms key.

```
    import boto3
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    content = '64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:06:51 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/rdiff/TWiki/NewUserTemplate?rev1=1.3&rev2=1.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4523'
   s3.put_object(Bucket=testbucket, Key='ex31/input.log', Body=content,ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms')
```